# Parsing two parameters with jquery ajax request and date format error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call with two parameters - number + date.

Currently the error that I got is:

```
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in...
```

This is the html part:

```html
<div class="textBox col-md-3 form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-append" id="">
        <input type="text" value="" maxlength="100" name="searchBox" placeholder="Number" class="form-control" id="search">
        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>          
    </div>
</div>   
<div class="form-group col-md-3">           
    <div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Date"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>  
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="searchBtn" /><br />
```

This is the ajax part:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function showLoader(){
    $('.search-background').fadeIn(200);
}

function hideLoader(){
    $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
    $('.search-background').fadeOut(200);
};

$(".searchBtn").click(function(){
    showLoader();
    $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);      
    $("#content #sub_cont ").load("getData.php?q=" + $("#date").val() + "&val=" + $("#search").val(), hideLoader());
});
```

This is the `getData.php`:

```php
include 'db.conn.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();

$rec = $_REQUEST['val'];
$q = date_create($_REQUEST['q']);
$date = date_format($q, 'Y-m-d');

if($date && $rec) {
    // query the database
```

If I remove this part `q=" + $("#date").val() +` which is for the date and leave search only by number there is not a problem and I got results. But I want to be able to search number for particular date.

Comment: @user5996818 There no field with `id="date"`.

Comment: Oh my god. How can I miss this. I really sorry for waste your time guys... silly me.

Comment: You should debug your own code before posting on SO

Comment: I know that I must but I don't really know how to do this when I make this jquery/ajax calls. When I dealing whit them ( rare ) mostly I use tutorials. Guess It's time to sit back and learn a bit for them. Thank's again

Comment: Your welcome. just accept the answer so that future readers will know answer to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There no field with `id="date"`

Just replace line

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Date"/>
```

with

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Date"/>
```